# Rails: Address model being used twice, should it be separated into two tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making an ecommerce site, and I have `Purchase`s which `has_one :shipping_address` and `has_one :billing_address`

In the past the way I've implemented this is to structure my models like so:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :billed_purchase, class_name: Purchase, foreign_key: "billed_purchase_id"
  belongs_to :shipped_purchase, class_name: Purchase, foreign_key: "shipped_purchase_id"

  belongs_to :state
end


class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base

  INCOMPLETE = 'Incomplete'


  belongs_to :user
  has_one :shipping_address, class: Address, foreign_key: "shipped_purchase_id"
  has_one :billing_address, class: Address, foreign_key: "billed_purchase_id"
  ...

end
```

As you can see, I reuse the `Address` model and just mask it as something else by using different foreign keys.

This works completely find, but is there a cleaner way to do this? Should I be using concerns? I'm sure the behavior of these two models will always be 100% the same, so I'm not sure if splitting them up into two tables is the way to go. Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** The original version of this was wrong. I have corrected it and added a note to the bottom.

You probably shouldn't split it into two models unless you have some other compelling reason to do so. One thing you might consider, though, is making the Address model polymorphic. Like this:

**First:** Remove the specific foreign keys from addresses and add polymorphic type and id columns in a migration:

```
remove_column :addresses, :shipping_purchase_id
remove_column :addresses, :billing_purchase_id

add_column :addresses, :addressable_type, :string
add_column :addresses, :addressable_id, :integer
add_column :addresses, :address_type, :string
add_index :addresses, [:addressable_type, :addressable_id]
add_index :addresses, :address_type
```

**Second:** Remove the associations from the `Address` model and add a polymorphic association instead:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
   ...
end
```

**Third:** Define associations to it from the `Purchase` model:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :billing_address, -> { where(address_type: "billing") }, as: :addressable, class_name: "Address"
   has_one :shipping_address, -> { where(address_type: "shipping") }, as: :addressable, class_name: "Address"
end
```

Now you can work with them like this:

```
p = Purchase.new
p.build_billing_address(city: "Phoenix", state: "AZ")
p.build_shipping_address(city: "Indianapolis", state: "IN")
p.save!
...
p = Purchase.where(...)
p.billing_address
p.shipping_address
```

In your controllers and views this will work just like what you have now except that you access the `Purchase` for an `Address` by calling `address.addressable` instead of `address.billed_purchase` or `address.shipped_purchase`.

You can now add additional address joins to `Purchase` or to any other model just by defining the association with the `:as` option, so it is very flexible without model changes.

There are some disadvantages to polymorphic associations. Most importantly, you can't eager fetch from the Address side in the above setup:

```
Address.where(...).includes(:addressable) # <= This will fail with an error
```

But you can still do it from the Purchase side, which is almost certainly where you'd need it anyway.

You can read up on polymorphic associations here: [Active Record Association Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

**EDIT NOTE**: In the original version of this, I neglected to add the `address_type` discriminator column. This is pernicious because it would seem like it is working, but you'd get the wrong address records back after the fact. When you use polymorphic associations, and you want to associate the model to another model in more than one way, you need a third "discriminator" column to keep track of which one is which. Sorry for the mixup!

Comment: Nice I was thinking about polymorphic associations too. I'll go with this! Thanks

Comment: Wait actually this doesn't work. There's no way to distinguish between `purchase.shipping_address` and `purchase.billing_address` in the database

Comment: @Edmund Ack! You're totally right. Super sorry for the mixup. I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to @gwcoffey 's answer.

Another option would be using [Single Table Inhertinace](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance) which perhaps suits more for that case, because every address has a mostly similar format.